# VB.NET convert 24hours mySQL TIME() to 12hours format

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Okay, I know there are similar post to this. But all I can see is they are using DATETIME() data type, mine is TIME() only.

I manage to store time using mysql time(now()). The format it stored is in 24hours format.

When I retrieve its value to some label in VB.NET I need to display it in 12 hours format. What I have done so far is the code below. but no luck.

```
 dataSet = New DataSet
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT timein_pm from dtr WHERE cats_id='" & Trim(lblId.Text) & "'"
        adapter.Fill(dataSet)

        Label6.Text = dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("timein_pm").ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

How do I do it? Also is it possible to do it via mySQL time format or something?

EDITED:

Database Values:

```
id        date          timein_pm        id
57      2013-12-04       15:24:13       0828
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a MySQL solution you can use [`TIME_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) function

```sql
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(timeout_pm, '%h:%i:%s %p') time_12h
  FROM dtr
 WHERE ...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cc34/2)** demo

Comment: wierd, this seems to be correct, but when I tested it . it just return 12:00 AM

Comment: It should work just fine. See updated sqlfiddle with your data. BTW in the query you select `timeout_pm` column but then refer to `timein_pm` column

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
string strMinFormat = dateTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");//12 hours format
```

try this....